# Add leading and trailing zeroes to a string/label in swift

Tags: swift, string

In swift I know how to set the number of digits after the decimal point when converting a double to a string:

```
String(format: "%0.2f", someDouble)
```

Similarly I know how to set the number of digits before the decimal point:

```
String(format: "%02d", someDouble)
```

But how can I do both?

I want the string to always have a 00.00 format.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You simply combine the two:

```
String(format: "%05.2f", someDouble)
```

The `0` means fill with leading zeros as needed.
The `5` means you want the final output to be at least 5 characters, include the decimal point.
The `.2` means you want two decimal places.

If this is a number you are showing to a user then you should probably use `NumberFormatter` so the decimal is properly formatted for the user's locale.